# Rules for simplifying expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, rule

I define a simple expression $\Omega$:

```
x1 = m3*Sqrt[3];
y1 = 0;
x2 = Sqrt[3]/2*(2*m3 - 1);
y2 = 1/2;
x3 = x2;
y3 = -y2;

r1 = Sqrt[(x - x1)^2 + (y - y1)^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x - x2)^2 + (y - y2)^2];  
r3 = Sqrt[(x - x3)^2 + (y - y3)^2];

Ω = (1 - 2*m3)/r1 + m3/r2 + m3/r3 + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);
```

I also define some rules:

```
rule1 = {m3*Sqrt[3] -> x10, 1/2*Sqrt[3]*(2*m3 - 1) -> x20};
rule2 = {((x - x10)^2 + y^2) -> r10, ((x - x20)^2 + (y - 1/2)^2) -> r20,
         ((x - x20)^2 + (y + 1/2)^2) -> r30};
```

When I compute the first derivative with respect to $x$

```
Ωx = D[Ω, x];
```

and I try to simplify it after applying my rules; i.e.,

```
Simplify[Ωx /. rule1 /. rule2]
```

I get the following output

[image]

As you can see, the rules work well in the second term, while on the other hand they fail in the third and fourth term. Why?

Any suggestions on how to simplify the output according to the above-mentioned rules?

Comment: Rules are applied to expressions in `FullForm`.  And, `rule1[[2]] // FullForm` does not match anything in `Ωx // FullForm`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I noted in a comment above, rules are applied to expressions in `FullForm`. And, `rule1[[2]] // FullForm` does not match anything in `Ωx // FullForm`.  Often, small changes can cause rules to work.  Here, for instance, define

```
rule1 = {m3*Sqrt[3] -> x10, Sqrt[3]*(2*m3 - 1) -> 2 x20};
```

Then,

```
Simplify[Ωx /. rule1 /. rule2]

(* x + ((-1 + 2 m3) (x - x10))/r10^(3/2) + (m3 (-x + x20))/r20^(3/2) + 
   (m3 (-x + x20))/r30^(3/2) *)
```

which may be the desired form.

So why did this seemingly inconsequential change help?  `rule1[[2]] // FullForm` as originally defined contained `Rational[1,2]`, while `Ωx // FullForm` contained `Rational[-1,2]`.  Redefining `rule1[[2]]` to eliminate the factor of `1/2` also eliminated this inconsistency between `rule1[[2]]` and `Ωx`.  Such behavior is not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the definitions using *SetDelayed* ie

```
x1[m3_] := m3*Sqrt[3];
y1 = 0;
x2[m3_] := Sqrt[3]/2*(2*m3 - 1);
y2 = 1/2;
x3[m3_] := x2[m3];
y3 = -y2;

r1[m3_, x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x - x1[m3])^2 + (y - y1)^2];
r2[m3_, x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x - x2[m3])^2 + (y - y2)^2];
r3[m3_, x_, y_] := Sqrt[(x - x3[m3])^2 + (y - y3)^2];

Ω[m3_, x_, y_] := (1 - 2*m3)/r1[m3, x, y] + m3/r2[m3, x, y] + 
 + m3/r3[m3, x, y] + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);
```

Then, I would perform the differentiation, ie

```
Ωx = D[Ω[m3, x, y], x]
```

Then I'd notice how

```
MapAt[f, Ωx, {{2, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {4, 4, 1}}]
```

singles out the specific parts I aim to transform, and I'd take it from there.